# merge two array objects into one with its own key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two objects are contained by an array for each. The following code works. However, I am feeling this code I wrote is a bit odd. I am seeking a better or more standard way to improve below code. Thanks

```js
  const a = [
    {
      apple: '1',
      banana: '2',
    },
  ];

   const b = [
    {
      apples: '1',
      bananas: '2',
    },
  ];

  const json1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...a));
  const json2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...b));

  console.log({ ...{a: json1}, ...{b: json2}})
```

the output needs to be

```
{
  "a": {
    "apple": "1",
    "banana": "2"
  },
  "b": {
    "apples": "1",
    "bananas": "2"
  }
}
```

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention previously, I don't want `a[0]` `b[0]`

Comment: do you have some other object in the arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz for now no, only two `a` and `b`

Comment: *"...a bit odd."* Inded. :-) `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is almost **always** an anti-pattern.

Comment: Do you mean `{a: a[0], b: b[0]}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: _"I don't want `a[0]` `b[0]`"_ Why not?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when `a` or `b` has more elements?

Comment: @jabaa thanks. I was just wanting to know if es6 can make `[{}]` to be `{}`

Comment: Why didn't you ask this instead? What's the expected behavior if the array contains more elements, e.g. `const a = [{banana: '1'}, {apple: '2'}]`?

Comment: @crashmstr thanks! I only have two `a` `b` so didn't think much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get an object for each array and assign to the wanted properties.

```js
const
    a = [{ apple: '1', banana: '2' }],
    b = [{ apples: '1', bananas: '2' }],
    result = { a: Object.assign({}, ...a), b: Object.assign({}, ...b) };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with

```js
const a = [{
  apple: '1',
  banana: '2',
}];

const b = [{
  apples: '1',
  bananas: '2',
}];

console.log({ a: a[0], b: b[0] })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current code is giving you the result you want, then you can just do this:

```
const result = {a, b};
```

Live Example:

```js
const a = [
    {
      apple: '1',
      banana: '2',
    },
  ];

   const b = [
    {
      apples: '1',
      bananas: '2',
    },
];

const result = {a, b};
console.log(result);
```

If you want to make copies of the objects, you can do this:

```
const result = {
    a: a.map(o => ({...o})),
    b: b.map(o => ({...o})),
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const a = [
    {
      apple: '1',
      banana: '2',
    },
  ];

   const b = [
    {
      apples: '1',
      bananas: '2',
    },
];

const result = {
    a: a.map(o => ({...o})),
    b: b.map(o => ({...o})),
};
console.log(result);
```

Or for a more generic deep copy operation, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).